# Strcmp and string comparison in PHP where string comes from an array

Tags: php, string-comparison

Here's what I'm trying to achieve, which at the moment returns "error", despite `$assign` holding the value A.

```
if ($assign === "A") {
    echo "Assign is A";
}
    elseif ($assign === "B") {
        echo "Assign is B";
}
    else {
        echo "error";
}
```

`$assign` is getting its value from an array, as shown below where I checked anything I could think of. The `strcmp` below returns -52, which has me stumped. `$assignments[0]` definitely holds "A", without any extraneous spaces or characters, and the type is definitely string.

```
$assign = $assignments[0];
print_r ($assign);
print (gettype($assign));
echo strcmp ($assign, "A");
```

I'm assuming that the issue is that I'm not assigning `$assign` the value "A" but instead some sort of reference to it as it comes from an array, but I'm afraid that's as far as my troubleshooting has gotten me!

Comment: `var_dump($assign)` and check what is in?

Comment: That returns string(12) " A "

Comment: @exlibris google -> `PHP trim()`

Comment: @exlibris  Rizier123's tip can help you.